# How to add UIElement to the Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, grid, wpf-controls

I have a Grid, in my Grid I put a canvas. Here is my grid:

[image]

I added a canvas to my grid. Here is my XAML code.

```
<Grid Name="grid1" ShowGridLines="True" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
        <Canvas Name="canvas1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="7" Panel.ZIndex="0">
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

My problem is: I can't see a UI Element I added to my grid.

Here is my c# code:

```
sliders = new List<Ellipse>();
            double leftMargin = 0;
            double rightMargin = 0;
            int diametrOfCircles = 50;
            double widthOfCanvas = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
            int placeBtwCircles = 30;
            double sum = 0;

            sum = widthOfCanvas - (GetNumberOfImages() * diametrOfCircles);
            sum -= (placeBtwCircles * (GetNumberOfImages() - 1));
            leftMargin = sum / 2;
            rightMargin = sum / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < GetNumberOfImages(); i++)
            {
                sliders.Add(new Ellipse());
                sliders[i].Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
                sliders[i].Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
                //sliders[i].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                //sliders[i].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                sliders[i].Width = 20;
                sliders[i].Height = 20;
                sliders[i].Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin + i * (placeBtwCircles + diametrOfCircles), 350, rightMargin + (numberOfImages - i - 1) * (placeBtwCircles + diametrOfCircles)
                    , 20);
                sliders[i].Opacity = 0.3;                
                Grid.SetRow(sliders[i], 2);
                Grid.SetColumn(sliders[i], 3);                
                //canvas.Children.Add(sliders[i]);
                Grid.SetZIndex(sliders[i], 1);
                grid1.Children.Add(sliders[i]);
                sliders[0].Opacity = 0.9;

            }
```

When I run my application, I can't see my sliders. Where have I done wrong?

Comment: Why is the canvas spanning across all the rows and columns? Did you try to removing the canvas?

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding to the _Canvas_ rather than to `grid1`?

Comment: I want to add animation. I can make animation only in the canvas. Animation is ready. And all UI elements have zindex = 1. Animation is background.

Comment: @MickyDuncan I do it with canvas too, fail. And with grid it will be better for me.

Comment: You put all Ellipses into row 2 and column 3. Does that make sense? Besides that it is entirely unclear what you are trying to do. What is the purpose of the Ellipses? What is the "background" Canvas for? Please add some details to your question to make it understandable for others.

Comment: @Clemens I want to see my Ellipses.

Comment: Off-topic perhaps, but adding something to a list like `sliders.Add(new Ellipse());` then immediately accessing it via `sliders[i].Stroke = ...;` is arguably long-winded and error-prone

Comment: arguably **unclear what you are asking**

Comment: You don't see the Ellipses because you're setting their Margin property. In a Grid, the Margin is relative to the Grid cell.

Comment: _"I want to see my Ellipses"_ - is not helpful

Comment: @Clemens I upgrade my question

Comment: the Thickness object needs to be constructed with (left,top,right,bottom)..it doesn't seems to me that you are following that here ! 
sliders[i].Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin + i * (placeBtwCircles + diametrOfCircles), 350, rightMargin + (numberOfImages - i - 1) * (placeBtwCircles + diametrOfCircles)
                    , 20);

Comment: @SamTheDev Besides that, the Margin should certainly not be set at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U don't see your sliders because of margin, fix logic behind the calculation of margin. 
Or u can put a stackpanel in that grid cell and put those sliders in stackpanel and set orientation to horizontal for example.

```
        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        stackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        stackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        Grid.SetRow(stackPanel, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(stackPanel, 3);
        this.grid1.Children.Add(stackPanel);

        var sliders = new List<Ellipse>();
        double leftMargin = 0;
        double rightMargin = 0;
        int diametrOfCircles = 50;
        double widthOfCanvas = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
        int placeBtwCircles = 30;
        double sum = 0;

        leftMargin = sum / 2;
        rightMargin = sum / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < GetNumberOfImages(); i++)
        {
            sliders.Add(new Ellipse());

            sliders[i].Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
            sliders[i].Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
            sliders[i].Width = 20;
            sliders[i].Height = 20;
            sliders[i].Margin = new Thickness(5);

            stackPanel.Children.Add(sliders[i]);
            sliders[0].Opacity = 0.9;
        }
```